# how to set value for attribute programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
  <declare-styleable name="MyColorsStyles" >
<attr name="RedColor" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>

  
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">       
    <item name="RedColor">#D32127</item>
</style>
```

this is how to set the RedColor to each theme.
but the question is how to set the RedColor value programmatically? and not by creating multiple themes?

Comment: You can't, themes are immutable.

Comment: ok @Nicolas but how can i change the colors of the textviews for example globally from the server? meaning if the server gave me blue the text is blue? should i make all the app programmatically coded like tvText.setTextColor(..) ?

Comment: Yes, change it programmatically.

Comment: omg thanks man for the help ;)